# How to recover cpp data from linux library files?

Tags: c++, file, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted a .cpp file with some valuable code of mine.
It was part of my own library: libandrissh.so
How can I recover it? I tried scalpel, but it did not find it.

I was wondering if I could somehow extract the info from my .so or .o other files that are in my library. I think this could be possible, because my programs using the library still work.

any suggestions?
thanks guys

Comment: Maybe if it was built in debug mode, it may be possible to retrieve that code? Code someone give us insight on that?

Comment: You can't revert compiled code to the original source. You're better off trying to recover the original file. Figure out which file system you're using, and then Google "<file system> recover deleted file"

Comment: This is why people use source control!

Answer (score 3):

If it's deleted and not in a recycle or trash bin you can't recover it easily from the compiled binaries. There are disassemblers to get you that far but I have not yet seen any decompilers that are production ready that can get you back to original sources. Even if they could it likely won't be able to recover the original symbol/variable names anyway.

Your best bet would be to look at something like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to search the free sectors on your hard disk. Despite its name, it actually finds many different file formats including video, music, documents, text and even C source files. As long as your files haven't been overwritten, you will likely be able to find it. I used it to recover a lot of data from my wife's hard drive when her filesystem became corrupt. Also, it's free under the GPL.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the library binary, you can of course disassemble it (use e.g. `objdump --disassemble libandrissh.so`), but going from the "bare" machine code back to a higher-level language like C++ is not easy. I'm not aware of any standard tools to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some disassembler like [IDAPro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Disassembler)

Depending on the compiler used, the flags and everything else you might get decent results.